# iPhone set interfaceorientation programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I am trying to change the orientation of a single `UIViewController` programmatically. The user should choose in the settings if the view will be portrait or not. The value will be saved in `NSUserDefaults` and in the specific `ViewController` the orientation should be changed. So if Portrait is on the `interfaceOrientation` should be on `UIInterfaceorientationUpsideDown`......

I used following method but it will only change the orientation when the user will turn the device to landscape/portrait... otherwise nothing will be triggered.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfactOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Furthermore i tryied the next one (also with method name "`setOrientation`"):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation: UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
```

But again, nothing happens, there just appear errors because xcode sayes there are no methods with this name.

But ther should be another way to change it programatically...
the first method is also just a method that handles the actionListener after device position but there should be a way to call this `actionListener` in a direct way....
I just looked inside the `UIApplication` File but there is no usefull method....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use something like this code:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(rotationChanged:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And then, change your view according to the orientation:

```
-(void)rotationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSInteger orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    UIWindow *_window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    switch (orientation) {
        case 1:
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

            [_window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (0)];
            [_window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 2:
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

            [_window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI)];
            [_window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 3:
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

            [_window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI / 2)];
            [_window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 4:
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

            [_window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (- M_PI / 2)];
            [_window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :P

Comment: i just selected 2 of the cases so that the user can select portrait yes or no. But so the screens of all Controller will change when i enter the game view controller.... and furthermore the first row of my tableview isn't displayed perfectly when set to landscape mode, but when changing the view again everything is ok. Does the menü have to be loaded again to be displayed well?

Comment: I have sort of the same problem… I hava a pure portrait app… except when YouTube video is played. 

When it starts, I rotate the view, but the player control is a little bit dislocated and I still didn't manage to fix it.

Comment: Hey russoedu, i just tested the app again. When i used the case 3 of your example so that the screen turns to landscape mode, the statusbar turns back to portrait when the device turns to any position and stays in portrait. when using case 1 everything works fine. Where is exactly the problem? Do i have to insert something into "shouldAutoRotateToInterface" or anything else?

Comment: As what you want is to keep the selected rotation, I think shouldAutoRotateToInterface AND the observer should be removed from the code, so the App stops "sensing" the rotation…

Answer (score 2):

Use this works perfectly on `iOS7` and earlier.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
           [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:yourDesiredOrientation];
```

You will then need to edit the shouldAutoRotate method (following example is for portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: it turns the StatusBar to the Orientation you choose and the emulator turns to the same position. But now i let the "shouldAutoRotate...." method return always true but nothing happens, the View stays in position "...Portrait".

Comment: In your "shouldAutoRotate" method, it should return true only if it is the desired orientation.  Otherwise, it will just turn back immediately, which might what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

From previous answer:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
           [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
```

**WARNING**

I haven't a possibility to comment this answer so I'll edit it.

The author of this answer tries to set a value of `UIInterfaceOrientation` type to a variable of `UIDeviceOrientation`. They are both `NSInteger` enums, so compiler will not show a warning/error. But they have different meanings and "device" additionally has "face up" and "face down" orientations.