# How to allow users to use application in particular orientations from within app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, device-orientation

I am working on an application in which using settings options i want user to choose his own preferred orientation for app be it portait,landscape or both...i want to save his preferred orientation & only allow user preferred orientation there after...if it's possible,how can i achieve this? thanks in advance..

Comment: Refer the below link to change the orientaion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109662/iphone-set-interfaceorientation-programatically

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to change the orientation manually,

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

save the orientation in nsuserdefaults like below,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"portrait" forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: @ravinder singh this link will help you "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615114/how-to-change-the-orientation-of-the-app-without-changing-the-device-orientation"